# apt-get install is not working in linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

```
E: The package python-blinker needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I have python3.6 installed in my operating system already.

Note : i have no .list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks !

Comment: DId you run apt-get update first ?

Comment: when i run apt-get update, it say 'Reading package lists... Done', that's it.

Comment: Can you paste the content of your /etc/apt/sources.list file ?

Comment: #deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.1 _Serena_ - Release amd64 20161213]/ xenial contrib main non-free - i can see only this line in /etc/apt/sources.list file

Comment: looks like you installed it from an iso file, add repos to your sources.list file and it will work. https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList